# No option to debug in Intellij

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

When I connect to an emulator (flutter project in IntelliJ) the debug option seems to disappear.  Why does this happen?

*(I have run a flutter clean)*

[image]

Comment: cold reboot in android studio seemed to do the trick

Comment: This happened to me after a JDK upgrade. I fixed it by deleting target and rebuilding, to completely clean the checkout.